# How to access htpasswd-protected page automatically

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, .htpasswd

I have a passwordprotected directory with htaccess and htpasswd.

The htaccess looks like this

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/you/safedir/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic

require user myusername
```

The htpasswd looks like this

```
myusername:password887
```

This password protected directory is named www.mydomainname.com/mystuff

Now, I want to access this page fram a iframe (with www.mydomain.com/mustuff/index.html as src) in index.php in my root, but I dont want to make the users fill in the username and password all the time, just keep them from entering the folder the src is in.

Is there a script that can fill out the username and password automatically without letting the "users" write the username and password all the time?

Answer (score 16):

You can src the frame with the username and password in the link itself:

```
http://myusername:password887@www.mydomainname.com/mystuff
```

But this sort of defeats the purpose of password protecting the directory since anyone can look at the page source and know the username/password, and not all browsers support this type of URL.

You could make it so the referer is checked when attempting to access the `/mystuff` directory, and if it's from where the iframe is embedded, allow access without prompting for a password. But the referer can be spoofed very easily.

Comment: not really man. This could be good if it works, because I really need to keep people from accessing the directory directly. The iframe is allready in a passwordprotected area with diabled right click, so I´ve got it as secured as I need :) thansk, I´ll try this

Comment: Just got this to work, it's exactly what I needed. In my case it doesn't matter if the password is exposed in source because the page in question won't display unless you're already logged in with appropriate privileges - those people are all allowed to have this password - the workaround is just for their convenience. Do you know which browsers this will fail in?

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no possibility, because htpasswd is for this use case